# Required xml attribute "adSize" was missing when trying to implement ads

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get ads on my android application but the banner says "Required xml attribute "adsize" was missing.

Here is my xml code for just the ads:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.ckudesigns.hqtriviaguide.Main2Activity"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitid="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

Here is my java code for just the ads:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-1802503500709247~1508244791");
    mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    addButtonClickListener();



    /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespace declaration for the `ads` namespace is incorrect. You have this:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.ckudesigns.hqtriviaguide.Main2Activity"
```

Instead, you should have this:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: I have done this originally, but I am still getting an error.